# lsof: restrict to sockets available via loopback

Tags: linux, networking, sockets, network-interface, lsof

I can restrict the selection to sockets listening only on the loopback interface:

```
$ lsof -p "$(pgrep -d, proga)" -i4TCP@127.0.0.1 -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n -a
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
proga   964 myuser  13u  IPv4  23377      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:54780(LISTEN)
```

But how can I select sockets listening on all interfaces (including loopback):

```
$ lsof -p "$(pgrep -d, progb)" -i4TCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n -a
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
progb  1134 myuser  19u  IPv4  18270      0t0  TCP *:12486(LISTEN)
```

...while excluding sockets not available via loopback?

```
$ lsof -p "$(pgrep -d, progc)" -i4TCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n -a
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
progc  4983 myuser  17u  IPv4  19846      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.22:9876(LISTEN)
```